# Twitter API: Oauth URL for a Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am working on a Wordpress Plugin and facing a Problem.

A User request was a Twitter integration. So I'm right now looking trough the OAuth Twitter API and creating a App to build the foundation.

As I was creating the App, I need a callback URL. But as it is a Wordpress Plugin which is installed on multiple Websites, I dont have a URL for that purpose.

My only Idea until now is to use a Webserver of my own to grap the OAuth callback and redirect it to the right URL. But as it is a OpenSource Plugin and I dont earn anything of it, I dont really want to spend money on it...

Does someone have an idea?

Thy for your help, Nico :)

PS: No, I'm not native English. How you know? ;D

Oh, BTW OAuth 1.0a

Answer (score -1):

You have two main choices:

1. You run your own webserver, with a callback, to handle this.
2. Your clients have to create their own Twitter API keys.

For 1., the flow goes like this:

`My blog -> Your Server -> Twitter OAuth -> Your server's callback -> My blog`

You would need to track which blog the user is coming from in order to redirect them back to the correct place.

Easier for you - but harder for the user - is to give them instructions on how to set up a developer account and then create a callback URl for their blog.